# select pyspark dataframe rows based on result of groupBy

Tags: sql, pyspark

I have a dataframe with three columns

```
ID | rank | score
1  | 1    | 20
1  | 2    | 30
2  | 4    | 50
2  | 6    | 100
```

I would like to select unique ids taking the row with the highest rank:

```
ID | rank | score
1  | 2    | 30
2  | 6    | 100
```

I tried this with a groupBy which sort of works, but as soon as include the score column, which differs in each row, then I only get returned the initial dataframe and the grouping based on the rank is lost (obviously).

Here is what I tried

```
data_grouped = data.groupBy("ID", "score")
data_grouped .agg({"rank":"max"}).orderBy("ID").show()
```

I feel like this should be achievable relatively easily but my sql / pyspark knowledge is lacking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `window` will be more **efficient and scalable**, than using a groupBy. You can compute maximum value of rank in each ID grouping, using `max` function and `window with partitionBy ID`, and then `filter` on `rank` and computed `maxrank`.

```
w= Window().partitionBy("ID")
df.withColumn("maxrank", F.max("rank").over(w)).filter("rank=maxrank").drop("maxrank").show()

+---+----+-----+
| ID|rank|score|
+---+----+-----+
|  1|   2|   30|
|  2|   6|  100|
+---+----+-----+
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to use the `partitionBy()` method:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html?highlight=partition#pyspark.RDD.partitionBy

I believe it does something similar to SQL's `PARTITION BY`:

https://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-window-functions/sql-partition-by/